# combine two mysql databases with different structure

Tags: mysql

i am developing a database for a web app with my friend and we have divided the tables amoungst ourselves so we both are develping 6 tables on our sepeate PCs using mysql my question is, is it possible to combine these two databses to create one database and if yes how can we do that and if not which other way can we use to complete our task

Comment: you can't easily combine two databases, short of doing `select ... from ... insert into ...` queries

Comment: This is not the correct way to proceed. You can keep your local database but the schema (structure) need to be shared. How can you, among other things, define relationship between tables? Take a look to some versioning and collaborations tool like git,cvs and so on (those tools will help you with code also).

Comment: Are you saying that you each have a database that has one table in it, and you want to put all the tables into one central database?  If so, then look at exporting each table from the various databases, and then importing those exported tables into the central database.

Comment: exactly we need to export the tables to a central database how can we go about it?

Comment: i suggest you take a look at navicat software